# C++ Handling My own Exception class

Tags: c++

I'm having problems to display some strings that I have in my subclasses. I'm trying to do it with a function but I'm not sure why I don't get the content of these strings.

```
class Employee{
    string FN, LN, JT;
    double Income;

public:
    char const *getters(){
        return FN.data(), LN.data(), JT.data(); //=========>getting the content of strings
    }
    virtual char const *getAccess()=0;
    Employee(char const *fn, char const *ln, char const *jt, double inc){

        if(fn==0) throw Exception(1, "Sorry, First Name is Null");
        if(ln==0) throw Exception(2, "Sorry, Last Name is Null");
        if(jt==0) throw Exception(3, "Sorry Job Title is Null");
        if(inc<=0) throw Exception(4, "Sorry, The Income is Null");

        FN=fn;
        LN=ln;
        JT=jt;
        Income=inc;
    }
};

class Programmer: public Employee{
public:
    Programmer(char const *fn, char const *ln, double inc):
        Employee(fn,ln,"Programmer", inc)
    {}
    char const *getAccess(){
        return "You have access to Meeting Room + Development Office";
    }
};

//=========The Main============
int main(){
    Employee *acc[3];

    try{
        acc[0]=new Programmer("Juan", "Villalobos", 60000);
        acc[1]=new Director("Jorge", "Villabuena", 70000);
        acc[2]=new ProdSupport("Pedro", "Villasmil", 80000);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            cout << acc[i]->getters() << endl;    //=============>Displaying the strings
            cout << acc[i]->getAccess() << endl;
        }
    } catch(Exception acc){
        cout << "Err:" << acc.getErrCode() << " Mess:" << acc.getErrMess() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, I'm guessing that my function is not doing what I want, which is display the first name and last name.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is so wrong I am not sure where to start...

Comment: I forgot to say that it only gets the last string which in this case is Job Title.. equal to JT.data()

Comment: What gave you the idea that you can return a list of strings as you are trying to do? There is only one return value from a function.

Comment: And data() is wrong for returning a string. Use c_str or there is no null termination guarantee.

Comment: Well, actually that was the answer of my professor for an exam question..  Which, I get it is wrong.. I'm just try to find the solution... if there is one using only 1 function to retrieve the 3 strings content..

Comment: And always catch exceptions as `const Exception &acc` otherwise it makes a copy, slices the exception class to just the base, and other weird, nasty things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the point of mixing `char*` and `string`. Prefer the later.

This does compile

```
char const *getters(){
    return FN.data(), LN.data(), JT.data();
}
```

but what you probably want is

```
char const *getters(){
    return (FN + LN + JT).data();
}
```

I would re-write your program like this:

```
class Employee{
    string FN, LN, JT;
    double Income;

public:
    string getters(){
        return FN + " " + LN + " " + JT;
    }

    virtual string getAccess()=0;

    Employee(string const &fn, string const &ln, string const &jt, double inc) :
        FN(fn), LN(ln), JT(jt), Income(inc)
    {
    }
};

class Programmer: public Employee{
public:
    Programmer(string const &fn, string const &ln, double inc):
        Employee(fn,ln,"Programmer", inc)
    {}

    string getAccess(){
        return "You have access to Meeting Room + Development Office";
    }
};

//=========The Main============
int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> acc;

    acc.push_back(Programmer("Juan", "Villalobos", 60000));
    acc.push_back(Director("Jorge", "Villabuena", 70000));
    acc.push_back(ProdSupport("Pedro", "Villasmil", 80000));

    for(size_t i=0; i<acc.size(); i++){
        cout << acc[i].getters() << endl;
        cout << acc[i].getAccess() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would go a step further and change the `for` loop to use an iterator instead of an index.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. you really extremely helped me.. I really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `,` comma operator is the right-hand value, so `return FN.data(), LN.data(), JT.data();` is effectively the same as `return JT.data();`, which is what you are seeing.

To do what you are attempting, try this instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> getValues() const {
    std::vector<std::string> arr(3);
    arr.push_back(FN);
    arr.push_back(LN);
    arr.push_back(JT);
    return arr;
}
```

```
std::vector<std::string> arr = acc[i]->getValues();
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = arr.begin(), end = arr.end(); iter != end; ++iter) {
    cout << *iter << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Or, move the `cout` logic into the class itself:

```
void displayValues() const {
    cout << FN << " " << LN << " " << JT << endl;
    cout << getAccess() << endl;
}
```

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    acc[i]->displayValues();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly but how can I make it work and get those 3 strings values from my function and return them to display the content.. ??